# how to implement many direction in one place on google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

i'm new about googlemap devlop with android, what i'm trying to do is  show two direction polyline or many polyline  to one place.

ex. "Hyde park" in Sydney
     has many route to reach that place.
     in one place show many direction Polyline to that place.

what should i do to create that? any refrences? please

Comment: you can use google direction api and get the polyline points and then draw the polyline

Comment: i'll try it thanks

Comment: the poly line can draw by a multiple draw on gmap? can create multiple polyline class?

Comment: if you check google direction api you'll see when you hit it putting source and destination it'll give you Lat/Lng coordinates for polyline in Json or xml format that you've to parse to draw the polyline. First have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

[Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start)

[Java Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)